# How to add multiple pages which can be switched on press of a button in pyGTK using quickly?

Tags: python, application-development, gtk

I am building my first app using quickly, pyGTK and python. I am confused how to add multiple pages to the same window and how to switch between multiple windows on click of button ?

In visual studio it is achieved very easie

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a `gtk.Notebook`?

To switch between pages, just use the notebook API in your button callback.

```
def on_button_clicked(button):
    # I want to go to page 2
    notebook.set_current_page(1)
    # Let's visit the next page
    notebook.next_page()
    # And back again
    notebook.prev_page()
```

http://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/class-gtknotebook.html